# Mediawiki 1.37 - VisualEditor - "Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server: (curl error: 28) Timeout was reached" (sometimes not always)

Tags: rest, timeout, mediawiki, parsoid

Please help, I am stuck. :)

I've searched related threads which could not help me.

My version of Mediawiki is 1.37.2

While editing a page with VisualEditor, I sometimes get the following error (Sometimes it works, sometimes I get the error ; it can work 10 times in a row and then don't work):

**"Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server: (curl error: 28) Timeout was reached"**

The error seems to occur whatever the page size. It happens on any page.

Note: I do not have this error on another test server with the same configuation.

---

In the log file I get :

```
[http] HTTP start: GET https://example.com/wiki/rest.php/example.com/v3/page/html/Language%2FMultiple-languages/129917?redirect=false&stash=true

[http] Error fetching URL "https://example.com/wiki/rest.php/example.com/v3/page/html/Language%2FMultiple-languages/129917?redirect=false&stash=true": 

(curl error: 28) Timeout was reached
```

---

I also sometimes get a timeout error when using this url directely in a browser:

https://example.com/wiki/api.php?action=visualeditor&paction=parse&page=Language/Multiple-languages

---

I never get an error if I do (using SSH):

curl https://example.com/wiki/rest.php/example.com/v3/page/html/Language%2FMultiple-languages/129917?redirect=false&stash=true

or

curl https://example.com/wiki/api.php?action=visualeditor&paction=parse&page=Language/Multiple-languages

---

My config in LocalSettings.php

```
wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );
$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable'] = 1;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-editor'] = "visualeditor";
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['writeapi'] = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to hosts file: 127.0.0.1 example.com

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this, I was skeptical on whether this answer without any explanation would work, but magically, it works! If anyone can do the kindness of giving us some explanation it would be great.